# Sharing JS functions between files without making them global or attaching them to a global object?

Tags: javascript

Say that I've got a function that I want to re-use between multiple files. I could just make it global but that's no good.

**master_file.js**

```
add = function(num1, num2){
  return num1 + num2;
};

subtract = function(num1, num2){
  return num1 - num2
};
```

**file1.js**

```
add(4,4);
```

**file2.js**

```
add(9,1);
```

**file3.js**

```
subtract(8,2);
```

Instead, I can create a global object and attach the functions as values of the global object (or the `window` object as others do).

**master_file_v2.js**

```
var add = function(num1, num2){
  return num1 + num2;
};

var subtract = function(num1, num2){
  return num1 - num2
};

global = {

  add: function(num1, num2){
    return add(num1, num2);
  },
  subtract: function(num1, num2){
    return subtract(num1, num2);
  }

};
```

Then I would have to call the functions like so.

**file1.js**

```
global.add(4,4);
```

**file2.js**

```
global.add(9,1);
```

**file3.js**

```
global.subtract(8,2);
```

Is there a way to *not* call the functions like this? I would prefer to directly call them by their names just like before, but without declaring them as global.

**file1.js**

```
add(4,4);
```

**file2.js**

```
add(9,1);
```

**file3.js**

```
subtract(8,2);
```

Comment: http://requirejs.org/, http://webpack.github.io/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid using globals (you should!), you should take a look at [CommonJS](http://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html) or [Harmony](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/) modules.

Using a module system would allow you to do things like this:

//utils.js

```
module.exports = function () {
  return {
    add: function (num1, num2) {
      return add(num1, num2);
    },
    subtract: function (num1, num2) {
      return subtract(num1, num2);
    }
  };
};
```

//file1.js

```
var add = require('./utils').add;
var subtract = require('./utils').subtract;

add(4,4);
subtract(8,2);
```

or event better using Harmony's destructuring feature:

```
var {add, subtract} = require('./utils');

add(4,4);
subtract(8,2);
```

Using modules makes your code more modular and makes code reuse easy while keeping your global scope clean.

Comment: Thanks. I now know why people use `modules`. Normally I would use this, but I'm using Meteor and I realize that this could conflict: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030979/sharing-meteor-functions-between-server-client-and-all-files-without-declaring

Comment: Ah sorry didn't know you were using Meteor. Unfortunately, since the whole Meteor coding style is build around global variables I don't think you will be able to improve your current solution.

Comment: Well, to be fair, I didn't mention Meteor because I didn't realize that it would be a big factor when it came to sharing functions. It was only when I read your response when I went "ohhhhh... crap" and realized I needed to make a separate but similar question just for the Meteor ecosystem, haha.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), but that was deprecated. The preferred method is to assign them to a local variable, basically the inverse of what you did in master_file

**file1.js**

```
var add = global.add
add(4,4);
```

**file2.js**

```
var add = global.add
add(9,1);
```

**file3.js**

```
var subtract = global.subtract
subtract(8,2);
```

Comment: Oh, I see, haha. That's pretty clever.