# Sharing Meteor functions between server, client, and all files without declaring them global?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Say that I've got functions that I want to re-use between multiple files on BOTH server and client. I could just make them global, place them into a `common` code folder, but that's no good.

**/lib/master_file.js**

```
add = function(num1, num2){
  return num1 + num2;
};

subtract = function(num1, num2){
  return num1 - num2
};
```

**/client/client_file1.js**

```
add(4,4);
subtract(10,3);
```

**/server/server_file1.js**

```
add(9,1);
```

**/server/file2.js**

```
subtract(8,2);
```

**--POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS--**

I can create a global object and attach the functions as values of the global object.

**/lib/master_file_v2.js**

```
var add = function(num1, num2){
  return num1 + num2;
};

var subtract = function(num1, num2){
  return num1 - num2
};

global = {

  add: function(num1, num2){
    return add(num1, num2);
  },
  subtract: function(num1, num2){
    return subtract(num1, num2);
  }

};
```

Then I would have to call the functions like so.

**/client/client_file1.js**

```
var add = global.add;
var subtract = global.subtract;
add(4,4);
subtract(10,3);
```

**/server/server_file1.js**

```
var add = global.add;
add(9,1);
```

**/server/server_file2.js**

```
var subtract = global.subtract;
subtract(8,2);
```

Is there a way to *not* call the functions like this? I would prefer to directly call them by their names but without declaring them as global.

**/client/client_file1.js**

```
add(4,4);
subtract(10,3);
```

**/server/server_file1.js**

```
add(9,1);
```

**/server/server_file2.js***

```
subtract(8,2);
```

**modules**

On the server side I *believe* I can use `module.exports` but modules isn't available on the client side, so that doesn't work. I could use a `modules` library for the client side but I think it might break with Meteor's unique code-sharing between the client and server in `/lib` if I were to declare `modules` there?

**Meteor.methods**

Calling them is pretty wordy and when defined in `/lib` they get run on both the client and server, which isn't always what you want...

Comment: Please develop "that's no good". What's bad in declaring globally stuff you will use globally? You can use a namespace if you're afraid of cluttering the global scope.

Comment: Well, for one there are functions with somewhat sensitive code that I wouldn't necessarily want someone to see. That's why I used a closure (dunno if that's the right word) in my `global` object example. But the global object usage can get a bit wordy IMO, so I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it without having to type `global.` each and every time I call a shared function.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do the global function calling thing without having to assign `global.functionName` to a `functionName` variable at the top of each new JS file each and every time I want to use a (or a group of) shared functions in a file.

Comment: Well, if you really do want some heavy encapsulation (!== hiding) you can use packages and export/import your API. Also, just because something is not global doesn't mean a motivated attacker won't find it (and exploit it if he can).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a piece of code not to be seen, you can't push it to the client. So you'll have put it in a `method`. That's the only meteor-native way. You can nicen up the `Meteor.call` api with something like this:

*lib/*

```
methodCaller = function methodCaller (methodName) {
  return function (/*arguments...[, callback]*/) {
    var callback = arguments.slice(-1)
    Meteor.apply(methodName, arguments, methodCallback)
  }
}

Meteor.methods({
  test: function (n) {
    return n*2
  }
})

test = methodCaller('test')
```

*anywhere*

```
test(1, function (err, result) {
  console.log(result)
})
```

If you are afraid of cluttering, just use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) or as you proposed, a simple object. You don't have to define a local-scope variable to use a function stored in an object. You can just use it like this:

*anywhere*

```
globals.add()
```

Now I think `globals` is to generic a name. That just moves the cluttering problem to a different place. In your example you could for an example define a `mathUtils` object instead.

I don't use closures very often. There are some cases where it can bring a big benefit. `once` is a good example of this:

```
once = function (func) {
  var hasBeenTriggered = false
  return function (/*arguments*/) {
    if(hasBeenTriggered) return
    hasBeenTriggered = true
    return func.apply(null, arguments)
  }
}
```

This might not look like most closures, but it is one. Here hiding `hasBeenTriggered` is essential for the integrity of the function. Try not to hide unnecessarily. Having lots of hidden functions makes it harder to write good tests.

Comment: Since we're dealing with scopes here, you should precise where each piece of code goes.